# How can I get a dropdown list like on Google survey site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, plugins

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1EsmzvERxWoUFd1P9CDOpGKR3oDa-oMEQIzFI-Ihryxc/edit
I will create my own university survey site.
I want to use a dropdownlist item adding structure like google forms in my project. Is there a plugin or bootstrap structure for this? If not, how can I do it easily?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw0ZJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your are creating a site using ASP.NET check this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: yes actually I can do it myself but my project needs to be completed in a certain time.
is a bootstrap available?

Comment: dropdown component in bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Have you checked the drop down list in google forms? Items in this drop-down list include checkbox, message box, etc. there is. I will try to let the user choose them.